# How to SUM a column based on 2 filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Given this example I need to write a formula in the G column which basically does this:

`sum C column if F(current row) = B(current row) AND E(current row) >= A(current row)`

The idea is to fill in more information in the ABC columns and just drop the formula in G to autofill. So the formula needs to work with columns. I tried using SUMIF but either I'm doing something wrong or it was not meant to be used like this. Is there some workaround to make this work?

Comment: Why does row 7 equal c2 + c7 ?

Comment: because the day changed from 1 to 2 so it needs to sum up value for user a in day 1 and day 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` with a dynamic range:

```
=SUMIF(B$2:B2,F2,C$2:C2)
```

[image]

Though this largely works because the days are in the same order and are the same size. Otherwise, by incorporating all the criteria you mentioned, then the below `SUMIFS` is more general:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,F2,A:A,"<="&E2)
```

Basically reads "sum column C if column B = F2 and if column A <= E2".

Comment: I think it's much better your second formula `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,F2,A:A,"<="&E2)` because as you pointed, if user changes order probably the first one won't work out as expected. So I like more second version. Upvoted :)

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! I've been struggling with this for a while. I made it work with the SUMIFS.